update a value in a dictionary using python
this is a challenge on the coddy.tech website:
Create a function named update_availability that allows you to update the availability status of a book in a library catalog. The function should take the library catalog, a title, and a new availability status as input parameters and update the availability status of the specified book in the catalog
def update_availability(catalog, title, new_availability):
   
        if title in catalog:
            catalog[title]['available'] = new_availability
        else:
            catalog[title]['available'] = False

a few of the test cases were passed but not all for some reason.
error code:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/NBGYDzQ2cahiwemgBpKXCVHd1l42/main.py", line 26, in &lt;module&gt;
    eval(line)
  File "&lt;string&gt;", line 1, in &lt;module&gt;
  File "/tmp/NBGYDzQ2cahiwemgBpKXCVHd1l42/main.py", line 8, in update_availability
    catalog[title]['available'] = False
KeyError: 'Harry Potter'


You're trying to change available value on the title that doesn't exist in the catalog. Instead, create new one:
def update_availability(catalog, title, new_availability):
    if title in catalog:
        catalog[title]["available"] = new_availability
    else:
        # at this point title isn't in the catalog, so create one:
        catalog[title] = {"available": False}  # or perhaps you mean `catalog[title] = {"available": new_availability}`

